# Time picker set up in React - jquery-timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have been trying to add this jquery plugin to a react project I am working on. I have been trying the different configs I have found in SO and the react documentation, but I can't find a way to make it work without freezing my development set up.

I have tried to import TimePicker from 'timepicker' as a react component and the integrating other libraries page options.

I would need to be able to retrieve the time written or selected by the user in a string format to be able to split it and send it to the back end.

Here is the plugin I am trying to use:

https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker

Comment: Please see creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
import React, { Component } from  'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import timepicker from 'timepicker'

class TimePicker extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.initDatepicker();
      }

  initDatepicker(){
    $(this.refs.timepicker).timepicker();
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <input className='timepicker' type='text' ref='timepicker' onBlur={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default TimePicker;
```

Comment: onBlur dispatch action mutliple times